# US treasury bills transfer

Tags: investing, international-transfer, transfer, treasury

Hi I have a question about US treasury bills

Currently I am in London looking to buy some - where do these bills get stored when they are purchased?  Im guessing its similar to a stock it's just held in my account through wherever I purchase it at?

My 2nd question is then say I moved from London (assuming I couldn't cash out my bills in the US because they are in a UK account) to the US how could I move that bill with me?  Is there a way to transfer the bill to a US investing account?

Comment: 1) What is your nationality. 2) Treasury Bills are short term, are you willing to hold them to maturity? 3) Is there a reason why you would want to be holding it in a UK account (I don't know the fees involved in currency conversion).

Comment: Im from London & will be moving to the US in a few weeks.  During this time I will still be holding some and I'm unsure of how to transfer them to the US